# How to select conversations involving the current user, using a left join

Tags: php, mysql

The following query selects the total count of a conversation participants but list all same conversations:

```
$id = 4;
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(1)'
       + ' FROM tbl_conversations AS a'
       + ' LEFT JOIN tbl_conversations_participants AS b'
       + ' ON a.id = b.conversation_id';
```

If I add this: `WHERE b.user_id = $id;` it shows correct number of conversations but all same conversations are listed.

Conversations table:

[image: Conversations Table]

Participants table:

[image: Participants Table]

Comment: Show your expected output based on some sample input

Comment: Spelling, grammar, and formatting

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for the number of participants participated in a particular conversation.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) totalParticipants
FROM tbl_conversations AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_conversations_participants AS b
ON a.id = b.conversation_id
WHERE a.id = 4;
```

If you only need the count then the following query suffices [no need to involve `tbl_conversations`]:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) totalParticipants
FROM tbl_conversations_participants 
WHERE conversation_id = 4;
```

**If you want to know the total participants for each conversation:**

```
SELECT
 a.id, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT b.user_id) totalParticipants
FROM tbl_conversations AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_conversations_participants AS b
ON a.id = b.conversation_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: I need to to know total conversation currently logged in user involved in

Comment: which field denotes the `logged in` status?

Comment: the id = 4 is the logged in user

Comment: which id? i mean in which table it does refer to?

Comment: sorry the user_id is something like 602, 603 in table conversations

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you intended to say. Please add your expected output based on the sample input you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand.

Why you use 2 table (**tbl_conversation**,**tbl_conversations_participants**) if you want to know only count of conversation with specific user just use only **tbl_conversations_participants** then count distinct **conversation_id**

Query look like :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.conversation_id) AS count_conversation
FROM tbl_conversations_participants a
WHERE a.user_id = $id
```